# Prove that the following series diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to prove that the series
$$
\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{z+p-1} - \frac{1}{z+p} - \frac{1}{z+p+1} - \cdots - \frac{1}{z+2p+q-1} + \frac{1}{z+2p+q} + \cdots, 
$$
in which $(p+q)$ negative terms always follow $p$ positive terms, is divergent.

Note that $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the denominator of each term is not $0$. I know it has something to do with the harmonic series but I am not sure how to give a formal proof. I think the hardest part is that $z$ is complex so we cannot use direct comparison test.

This is a question from A Course of Modern Analysisby E.T. Whitaker & G.N. Watson.

Comment: Try pairing them off; if the series converged, there must be the same number of plus and minus signs.

Comment: It seems to be converging if $p=q=1$, $z=2$.

Comment: @JCAA Even when there are more negative terms than positive terms? If $p = q = 1$, then we will have 2 negative terms follow by one positive term. I wish the problem would specify what $p$ and $q$ are. I think they are positive integers.

Comment: I would think a comparison with a harmonic series would work.

Comment: @MichaelHardy But comparison test is applied to a series of real numbers

Comment: @Smith : I'm guessing some algebraic fiddling with absolute values might take care of that.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If I know how, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: You can add positive terms in each positive group and negative terms in each negative group. You will get an alternating series.

Comment: @JCAA, but I thought the question asks us to show the series diverges.

Comment: Again, try the case $p=q=1$. I do not know whose question it is but I am skeptical. Also if $z=0$ ( a complex number) then what is the value of the first term of the series. Perhaps it diverges as a function seties?

Comment: @JCAA We are assuming each denominator is not zero, so $z \ne 0$. This question is from Math Tripos 1904.

Comment: The OP does not say that $z$ is not 0. It only says it is complex. Can you at least look at the question and make it reasonable? Either the question is wrong or you copied it incorrectly. Also it is not civilize to copy a text without reference.

Comment: @JCAA I just added the resource. I don't expect the question to be wrong since it is true for $z \in \mathbb{R}$. I can cite the whole problem for you. "Shew that the series $\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+1}+\frac{1}{z+2}-\frac{z}{3}+\cdots$" is conditionally convergent, except for certain exceptional vales of $z$; but that the series $\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{z+p-1} -\frac{1}{z+p}-\frac{1}{z+p+1} - \cdots - \frac{1}{z+2p+q-1} + \frac{1}{z+2p+1} + \cdots$, in which $(p+q$) negative terms always follow $p$ positive terms, is divergent.

Comment: @JCAA I actually looked at the wrong problem. This is not from Math Tripos 1904. I am taking it back. I think $z \ne 0$ for obvious reasons since it will make it undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch of the proof first consider the series starting at $m=1$ since the $1/z$ term makes no difference (this for simplicity so we can use $z=0$ in what follows):

Note that $|\frac{1}{z+m} - \frac{1}{m}|=\frac{|z|}{m|m+z|} \le \frac{1}{m^2}, m \ge m_K \ge 1$ when $z$ is fixed in a compact set $K$ away from the negative integers since we can take $m_k \ge 2\max_K |z|+1$ for example (in particular we can take the compact set $K_z=${$z$})

This immediately means that the given series (for an allowed fixed $z$) has the same behavior as the series with $z=0$ (starting at $m=m_{z} \ge 1$) and that is obviously divergent if the negative blocks are strictly bigger than the positive blocks by the same amount - to see that, group the $p$ positive terms with the first $p$ negative terms and that gives terms $\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+p}=\frac{p}{m(m+p)}$ which are absolutely convergent (assuming $p,q \ge 1$ as $p,q$ are fixed), while in every $2p+q$ consecutive block, we remain with $q$ negative terms so that sum is divergent as it is at most $\sum_{n \ge n_k} \frac{-1}{(2q+p)n+p+q}=-\infty$

(edit later)- as asked let me show how one proves the divergence of $1/3-1/4-1/5+1/6-1/7-1/8...$ so more or less the case $p=1, q=1$ where we ignore the first few terms so we can use $0$ as noted; take the partial sums

\begin{align}
s_3 & =1/3-1/4-1/5=(1/3-1/4)-1/5=b_1-1/(6-1) \\[6pt]
s_6 & =(1/3-1/4)+(1/6-1/7)-1/5-1/8 \\[6pt]
& =b_1+b_2-1/(6-1)-1/(9-1),
\end{align}
so

$$s_{3n}=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n-\sum_{2 \le k \le n+1}\frac{1}{3k-1}$$

and note that since each partial sum is a sum of finitely many terms we can recombine them as we wish; it is clear that $\sum {b_k}$ is absolutely convergent, so $s_{3n} \to -\infty$, hence the original series is divergent; it is obvious that $s_{3n}-s_{3n \pm 1} \to 0$ so the original series is indeed divergent to $-\infty$

for arbitrary $p,q \ge 1$ we use $s_{(2p+q)n}$ instead and same proof as above; with a little more work, noting that each positive block added from $s_{(2p+q)n+1}$ to $s_{(2p+q)n+p}$ is bounded, we get that $s_m \to -\infty$ so the series diverges to minus infinity in general too

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you why when you combine the first $p$ positive terms and the first negative terms, you get $\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+p}$? What happens to the other terms? Are we allowed to rearrange the terms like that??? Maybe I just don't understand fully. @Conrad

Comment: added the explanation for that

Comment: Can I ask you another question? I only took college-level analysis classes so there is still a lot of stuff that I don't understand. I know that the value of $z$ does not change the behavior of the series since it is constant anyway. But what theorem did you use to show that  $z$ does not matter? If there is a resource that I can read about that, that will be great. @Conrad

Comment: the comparison theorem - the series $S(z)$ is written as $S$ (fixed independent of $z$, the one with alternating harmonic numbers) plus $T(z)$, with $T(z)$ absolutely convergent; this means that $S(z)$ behaves the same as $S$ as convergence, limit points etc and since $S \to -\infty$ it followd that $S(z)$ diverges in a very precise way ( eg the imaginary part of $S(z)$ converges absolutely, real part goes to $-\infty$); any basic book on complex analysis should have this type of stuff - it depends on what your goal is to be more specific

Comment: What does the comparison theorem for the complex series state? I took a complex variable class but not complex analysis. I tried to google it but found nothing. The reason why I asked this question is that I don't fully understand the second paragraph. I know that the second paragraph is supposed to show that we can use $z = 0$ instead of other fixed complex numbers, but I don't understand how the second paragraph supports that idea. Everything else makes sense to me and I appreciate your work.

Comment: the comparison theorem says that if $|a_n(z)| \le M_n(K), z \in K$ (usually compact) and $\sum M_n < \infty$ then $\sum a_n(z)$ uniformly convergent on $K$; then if $|a_n(z)-b_n(z)| \le M_n$ as above then $\sum a_n(z), \sum b_n(z)$ have the same behaviour; this is useful for example if  $b_n$ is constant or has a nicer form; in the case here we can take $b_n=a_n(0), n \ge 1$ as $a_n(z)=1/(n+z), b_n=1/n$